# finite global dimension vs integral Domain

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

For the quotient of polynomial rings over complex number field,

its global dimension is finite is equivalent to it is domain.

is this true?

Answer (score 1):

No, but Serre proved that for noetherian local rings having finite global dimension is the same as being regular.

So, choose any non-regular local ring which at the same time an integral domain such as the localization of the cuspidal curve at the origin:

$$ k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(y^2-x^3)k[x,y]_{(x,y)} $$

Comment: I am considering the quotient of polynomial. So, I do not think this is a counter example. 

Comment: Yes, technically, $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ is your counter example then. See this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59981/global-dimension-and-localization

Answer (score -2):

It is true. If global dimension of $R$ is finite say $ = r$ then for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ we have homological dimension of $R_\mathfrak{m}$ is finite and $\leq r$. By Serre's result $\dim R_\mathfrak{m}$ = global dimension of $R_\mathfrak{m}$. It remains to note that there exists at least one maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ with global dimension of $R_\mathfrak{m}$  equal to $r$.
This is so since

$$ r = \max \{ hdim \ R_\mathfrak{m} \ \mathfrak{m} \ \text{a maximal ideal of $R$} \}.$$

Comment: Assume $R$ is a domain and prove it has finite global dimension. Let's see how you prove it. (It's false!)

Comment: I was under the impression that $R$ has finite global dimension


Comment: Tony: You may be confusing "global dimension" with "finitistic global dimension".

Global dimension is the biggest projective dimension of any R-module (and since $R / m$ has infinite projective dimension for some maximal ideal $m$ if $R$ isn't regular, gldim$(R) = \infty$).  However, the *finitistic* global dimension (i.e. the supremum of the projective dimensions of all the $R$-modules that *do* have finite projective dimension) is, if I remember correctly, the Krull dimension of the ring $R$, assuming $R$ is Noetherian.

It still has nothing to do with $R$ being a domain or not, though.

Comment: TO Tony： what is the meaning of hdim in" r=max hdim R_m" ?thanks a lot

Comment: To Neil Epstein, do you have an example? thanks

Comment: @iff: Do you mean an example of a ring whose finitistic global dimension is different from its (non-finitistic) global dimension?  Okay, sure.  Let $(R,m,k)$ be any Noetherian local ring that is not regular (e.g. Andrew Stout's example above).  By Auslander-Buchsbaum-Serre, the residue field $k$ has infinite projective dimension; hence gl.dim$R=\infty$.  On the other hand, by the Auslander-Buchsbaum theorem, for any $R$-module $M$ of finite projective dimension, its projective dimension is the difference between the depth of $R$ and the depth of $M$.  So the maximum possible finite pd is...

Comment: ...when $M$ has finite projective dimension and zero depth, and in such a case, pd $(M) = d$, where $d=$depth $R$.  This occurs, for instance, if $x_1, \ldots, x_d$ is a maximal regular sequence and $M = R/(x_1, \ldots, x_d)$.  In fact in that case, the Koszul complex on the elements $x_1, \ldots, x_d$ is a minimal projective resolution of $M$.  So the upshot is: if $R$ is any Noeth local ring that isn't regular, its global dimension is infinite, but its finitistic global dimension is its depth (which is always bounded above by its dimension, hence always finite).

Comment: to iff
$hdim$ stands for global homological dimension. In the local case it is finite iff $R$ is regular local.

If $R$ is not local then one can show that
$hdim R = $ max of all local  hdim.
